# Output Conditional Max Record For Each Instance Based on Several Columns

Tags: python, excel

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3F19.png)

Let's say each instance can have up to 20 columns/5 sets of 4 variables (I know it's not like that in the screenshot, but you get the idea): "YearA","Attrib1A","Attrib1B","Attrib1C","YearB",etc. Not all the records have the same amount of columns populated (eg. Record 1 could have Year1-5 and their associated attributes populated, but Record 2 could have only Year1 and Attr1A-Attrib1C populated, the rest blank).

I want to create 4 new columns Year, Attrib1,Attrib2, Attrib3. Based on YearI from 1-5 for each record, I want only want the max Year and it's associated attributes if the year is in between 2008-2010. For instance, let's say a record has Year1=2008, and Year2=2009, I want the new variable "Year" to be populated with 2009, and then Attrib2A, Attri2B, etc. be populated in Attrib1, Attrib2, etc.. Does that make sense? If there are no records that meet that criteria, then no record is populated. I also want to count the number of instances that a year is in between 2008-2010. Please see the attached screenshot as an example..

I'm honestly clueless on how to do this in excel (am more of a novice). I kind of see it as a python dictionary except in excel (but not sure how I would do it in Python either). I wouldn't even know how to link each year with it's associated attributes either...any thoughts/tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be an easy question on Excel, but how will you work?

Comment: If it's so easy, would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Cell N2:

```
=IF(OR(MAX(B2,F2,J2)="",MAX(B2,F2,J2)<2008,MAX(B2,F2,J2)>2010),"",MAX(B2,F2,J2))
```

Cell O2:

```
=IF(N2="","",IF(N2=B2,C2,IF(N2=F2,G2,IF(N2=J2,K2,""))))
```

Cell P2:

```
=IF(N2="","",IF(N2=B2,D2,IF(N2=F2,H2,IF(N2=J2,L2,""))))
```

Cell Q2:

```
=IF(N2="","",IF(N2=B2,E2,IF(N2=G2,I2,IF(N2=J2,M2,"")))
```

Then Drag down.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm misunderstanding your logic, this wouldn't include cases where there are years between 2008-2010, and years outside that range. Any thoughts on only finding the max for years between 2008-2010, and then the associated attributes? So I'd actually exclude cell J2 since it's not in that range, and compare B2 and F2 for the max?

Comment: I already edit it. Regarding the number of instances that a year is in between 2008-2010, for the values on N column, on B column... where exactly?

Comment: The logic should be generalized though, J2 should still be in the logic, it just wouldn't be compared since it doesn't fit the 2008-2010 condition. Does that make sense?

Comment: The number of instances are the number of years in each row that fall between 2008-2010. I suppose a solution to this would be to create an IF statement for each year column, then add 1 if between the years.

Comment: I don´t understand what is the benefit to add J2 on the formula if it is not on between 2008-2010, so it is not necessary for the condition. Regarding the counting, still you are not saying in which column it is required to make the sum, so imagine that it is on column b `=COUNTIFS(B:B,">=2008",B:B,"<=2010")`

Comment: Because other rows may have a year between 2008-2010 in the J column.